# Rendering time before or after an event

Tags: fullcalendar

I have events with a "buffer" time before or after like "prep work" or "driving time". I'm trying to figure out how to display this. Some pseudo code of my data:

```
{
  start: 11am,
  end: 11:30am,
  preptime: 5 minutes
}
```

The ideal thing would be to show an event that starts at 10:55, but with a different style for those first 5 minutes. Can you think of any way to accomplish this?

Comment: the easiest way would be to split it into two event objects on the calendar, then you can easily set a separate colour for each.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, this will subtract prep time from start of event and shade it (percentage) differently than rest of event. Tested in Firefox 54, Chrome 58, Edge, IE11.

https://jsfiddle.net/wp3nyax7/

```
$(function() {
  var preptime = 'preptime'; /* name of property that holds prep time (minutes!) */

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [{
      title: 'Event 1 has prep time',
      start: moment(),
      end: moment().add(30, 'minutes'),
      preptime: 5
    }, {
      title: 'Event 2 no prep',
      start: moment().add(1, 'hour'),
      end: moment().add(1.5, 'hour')
    }],
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
      // if there is a prep time, calculate how much to shade and make gradient for it
      if (event.hasOwnProperty(preptime)) {
        var prep = event[preptime];
        var length = event.end.diff(event.start, 'minutes') - prep;
        var ppct = (prep / length).toFixed(2) * 100;
        makeGradients(element, ppct);
      }
    },
    /* subtract prep time (minutes!) from start of event */
    eventDataTransform: function(eventData) {
      if (eventData.hasOwnProperty(preptime)) {
        eventData.start.subtract(eventData[preptime], 'minutes');
      }
      return eventData;
    }
  });

  function makeGradients(element, ppct) {
    /* gradient info found via http://gradcolor.com/css3-gradient.php */
    /* All these prefixed editions may not be necessary? Didn't bother to find out */
    var prefixes = ['', '-moz-', '-ms-', '-o-', '-webkit-'];
    var color1 = '#992222',
      color2 = '#229922';
    var grad = 'linear-gradient(left, {color1} {pct}%, {color2} {pct}%)'
      .replace('{color1}', color1)
      .replace('{color2}', color2)
      .replace(/{pct}/g, ppct);
    $.each(prefixes, function(i, v) {
      element.css('background-image', v + grad);
    });
    /* also -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right bottom, color-stop(%,color1), color-stop(%, color2)) */
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the ideas! @smcd had the solution I needed then I started to better understand the data I've got and had to revise my thinking a bit. The gradient idea allowed the event to remain intact and be resized and dragged which is great.

The change in my data meant that the buffer time isn't a part of the start and end times. Instead it's an additional field. So a 9am - 10am appointment with a 5 minute buffer still needs to be read and written back as 9-10 rather than 8:55 - 10. This matches the customer experience as well since they are thinking of 9am - 10am events. They do need to see that there's additional time required.

My solution was to add classes to the events objects like: .buffer-5, .buffer-10, .buffer-15 to support 5 minute intervals. From there I use the slotWidth value to determine the size to display. Using :before I add a slightly transparent shaded region showing the "buffer" time.

This approach has one caveat: buffer times may overlap appointments rather than pushing them onto new lines. this might be desirable though.

In the end, the buffer data is being treated more like helper text so I think it's the right solution.

Thank you!